# Catalog price rule not working after supee8788 installed

Tags: magento-1.9, php

After I have installed SUPEE8788, catalog price rule is not working. When I click save and apply button, the rule works for a limited period and then it stops working but shows the price in category page but not applied. If I make the rule inactive and click the save and apply button, the rule works. Why this is happening?

Comment: how did you confirmed it is caused by 8788?

Comment: It worked fine before the patch(8788) is applied.

Comment: I have checked the `cron_shedule` table but it has no job_code named `catalogrule_apply_all`. Can anyone help to resolve the issue.